# DevPartner's Metric Publisher

Tags: java, devpartner

I am using DevPartner (for Java) with pretty good results. However, there's a "metric publishing" utility which I can't use.

The problem is that said utility (pubmetrics.exe) asks for a site/port/user/password combination which I don't know. It pre-fills the site/port data with the localhost and thus I assume it's trying to contact the local DevPartner, but DevPartner isn't using any user and password that I'm aware of.

The electronic manual doesn't help much, either. Does anyone know how to use the utility?

Answer (score 0):

Ricardo, the PubMetrics utility was part of the Compuware offering called Optimal Delivery Manager. It was a team-based solution that tied high level management outputs from DevPartner, QACenter, Optimal Trace, and other CPWR tools into the Changepoint project management portal. All that the PubMetrics utility in DevPartner Java actually did was compute some derivative values from either profiler or static analysis session files and post those values as an XML document up to the Changepoint reporting engine. There is no real use of just the PubMetrics publisher by itself without the messaging backbone of the Optimal Delivery Manager system. Hope this helps.  -MPS  PS. So you know, the DevPartner product line is now offered by Micro Focus. Check out http://www.microfocus.com/products/micro-focus-developer/devpartner/index.aspx. Moreover, consider this a shameless plug since I am a Micro Focus employee and deeply engaged in the DevPartner product line. Cheers.